# Laravel 8 test GET http request false positive

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I'm trying to write a test with some assertions.
Here is an example of simple GET request and I expect it to fail since text is missing on page. However, it gives me green. When I check the response content I clearly see it throws error. I'm using laravel 8.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\Concert;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ViewConcertListingTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /** @test */
    function user_can_view_a_concert_listing() {
        $concert = Concert::create([
            'title' => 'The Red Chord',
            'subtitle' => 'with Animosity and Lethargy',
            'date' => Carbon::parse('December 13, 2016 8:00pm'),
            'ticket_price' => 3250,
            'venue' => 'The Mosh Pit',
            'venue_address' => '123 Example Lane',
            'city' => 'Laraville',
            'state' => 'ON',
            'zip' => '17916',
            'additional_information' => 'For ticket, cal (555) 555-5555.',
        ]);

        $view = $this->get('/concerts/'.$concert->id);

        $view->assertSee('The Red Chord');
        $view->assertSee('with Animosity and Lethargy');
        $view->assertSee('December 13, 2016');
        $view->assertSee('8:00pm');
        $view->assertSee('32.50');
        $view->assertSee('The Mosh Pit');
        $view->assertSee('123 Example Lane');
        $view->assertSee('Laraville, ON 17916');
        $view->assertSee('For tickets, call (555) 555-5555.');
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I check the response content I clearly see it throws error" what does this mean? What error message do you see? A couple of suggestions: you should look into factories for test model creation, you should use the `route()` helper instead of URLs, and you can reduce your code by chaining methods. E.g. `$this->get('/concerts/' . $concert->id)->assertSee('x')->assertSee('y')->assertDontSee('z');`

Comment: the test does not fail, but it succeeds. Thats what I mean by "When I check the response content I clearly see it throws error".

Answer (score -1):

```
 protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp(); 
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

}
```

laravel automatically "handles" the exception behind the scenes and never throws it on our tests. To handle this ourselves we need to use withoutExceptionHandling() method

Comment: Anything throwing an exception would still fail the test. All your code does is make the testing halt at the exception because it's uncaught.

Comment: Do I have to do that for every single test class?

Comment: no ,personally i use it in the function before the action when the test return  success and it should return false like when you use auth middleware